# Что нужно сделать, чтобы при масштабирование и отражении, SVG-объект остался на прежнем месте

Tags: html, вёрстка, svg

Как мне легче всего сначала масштабировать объект, скажем, в 2 раза больше его текущего размера, а затем перевернуть его вертикально и горизонтально, или и то, и другое вместе?

На данный момент я могу либо установить `scale (2,2)`, чтобы он стал в 2 раза больше его ширины и высоты, но я не могу перевернуть его одновременно со шкалой (-1, 1) для вертикального отражения.

Я создаю объекты SVG программно, как формат для экспорта.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Scale and mirror SVG object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23899718/7394871) от участника  [@Deukalion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1364750/deukalion).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/23899718/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы применить масштабирование и отражение, просто перечислите оба в своем `transform`:

`transform="scale(2,2) scale(-1,1)"`

Или просто объедините значения:
`transform="scale(-2,2)"`

Конечно, проблема, связанная с отрицательными масштабами, заключается в том, что объекты переворачиваются через начало координат (вверху слева) SVG, поэтому они могут выходить за границы документа.
Вы должны исправить это, добавив также `translate(x y)`.

Например, представьте, что у нас есть документ размером `100 × 100`.

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <polygon points="100,0,100,100,0,100”/>
</svg>
```

Чтобы перевернуть это вертикально, вы делаете:

`<polygon points="100,0,100,100,0,100" transform="scale(2,-2)"/>`

И чтобы исправить перемещение за кадр (зону видимости), вы можете либо ...

**(вариант 1)**
Сдвинуть его отрицательно перед переворачиванием (чтобы оно перевернулось обратно на экран):

`<polygon points="100,0,100,100,0,100" transform="scale(2,-2) translate(0,-100)"/>`

(`translate` здесь указан вторым, потому что списки преобразования эффективно применяются справа налево)

**(вариант 2)**
Или вы можете сдвинуть его положительно (по уже масштабированному размеру) впоследствии:

`<polygon points="100,0,100,100,0,100" transform="translate(0,200) scale(-2,2)"/>`

Пример кода:

```html
<!-- Начальная фигура -->
<svg width="200" height="200">
    <polygon points="100,0,100,100,0,100"/>
</svg>

<!-- Увеличиваем в два раза и отражаем вертикально, затем возвращаем в зону видимости -->
<svg width="200" height="200">
    <polygon points="100,0,100,100,0,100" transform="scale(2,-2) translate(0,-100)"/>
</svg>

<!-- Увеличиваем в два раза и отражаем горизонтально, затем возвращаем в зону видимости -->
<svg width="200" height="200">
    <polygon points="100,0,100,100,0,100" transform="scale(-2,2) translate(-100,0)"/>
</svg>
<!-- Увеличиваем в два раза и отражаем горизонтально, вертикально, затем возвращаем в зону видимости -->

<svg width="200" height="200">
    <polygon points="100,0,100,100,0,100" transform="scale(-2,-2) translate(-100,-100)"/>
</svg>
```

**Update**

Чтобы перевернуть (в положении) уже существующий объект, который находится где-то на экране. Сначала определите его ограничивающий прямоугольник (minX, minY, maxX, maxY) или centreX, centreY, если вы уже знаете это.

Затем добавьте следующее к его трансформации:

```
translate(<minX+maxX>,0) scale(-1, 1)   // для flip X
translate(0,<minY+maxY>) scale(1, -1)   // для flip Y
```

или, если вы знаете координаты центра, то вы можете использовать:

`translate(<2 * centreX>,0) scale(-1, 1)   // для flip X`

Для вашего примера в вопросе

```
<rect x="75" y="75" width="50" height="50"  transform="translate(-100, -100)
 scale(2, 2)   scale(1, 1) rotate(45, 100, 100)" />
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="400"  >
    
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
    
    <rect x="75" y="75" width="50" height="50"  transform="translate(-100, -100) scale(2, 2) scale(1, 1) rotate(45, 100, 100)" fill="url(#grad1)" stroke="black"/>
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="5" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
    
    <line x1="200" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
    <g transform="translate(200,0)">
        <!-- ^ этот элемент группы просто для того, чтобы мы могли переместить новый объект, и чтобы мы могли видеть оба объекта -->
    
    <rect x="75" y="75" width="50" height="50"  transform="translate(200,0) scale(-1, 1) translate(-100, -100) scale(2, 2) scale(1, 1) rotate(45, 100, 100)" fill="url(#grad1)"  stroke="black"/>
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="5" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />

    </g>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Scale and mirror SVG object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23902773/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>